# Where will MongoDB "forEach" commands run?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

**Scope:**

I have several MongoDB collections that need to be "fixed" (price normalization and change of some attributes values and names) hosted on a server.

To fix those, i am currently executing a [foreach command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/) on the [Robomongo tool](http://robomongo.org/) locally (not on the server), but the process is taking a bit longer than i expected.

This is one of the commands i am running to fix the price on the collections.

```
 db.Products_PoC.find().forEach( function(myDoc) {
    myDoc.price = (myDoc.price.toFixed(2)) * 100;
    db.Products_PoC.save (myDoc);
});
```

**Troubleshooting:**

After a quick troubleshoot, it seems like the tool is running this operation on the client-side, instead of all server-side (which would be way faster). A quick glance at the Task Manager shows the network usage of the Robomongo process going up to 5.5 mb/s.

**Question:**

Is there any way i can run commands like this on the server, instead of locally ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use *eval* function to run code on the MongoDB server. For example:

```
db.eval(function() { 
     db.Products_PoC.find().forEach( function(myDoc) {
        myDoc.price = (myDoc.price.toFixed(2)) * 100;
        db.Products_PoC.save (myDoc);
      });
    });
```

More about eval [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.eval/). Pay attention that *db.eval* will take global write lock on your database.

Comment: Is the lock issued on a Database level or Collection level?
Is there any way to run a "Collection.Eval()" or something that will only lock a specific collection?

Comment: @MarcelloGrechiLins, I believe it's on Database level, and not sure about if it's possible to do it on a Collection level. But you can use [eval](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/eval/) command with _nolock_ option.